# Simple form: html attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

How can I paste custom html attribute `data-uk-toggle` into simple_form label like

```
<span class="uk-button" data-uk-toggle="{target:'.my-class'}">...</span>
```

I tried

```
<%= g.label :self_estimation, class: 'km-180-label', input_html: { "data-uk-toggle" => "{target:'.my-class'}" } %>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm confused, are you using the simple_form gem?

Comment: @AnezioCampos, exactly

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
<%= g.input :self_estimation, label_html: { class: 'km-180-label', :data-uk-toggle => "{target:'.my-class'}" } %>
```

You can find more details here [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%= g.input :self_estimation, label_html: { class: 'km-180-label', "data-uk-toggle" => "{target:'.my-class'}" } %>
```

OR

```
<%= g.input :self_estimation, label_html: { class: 'km-180-label', data: {uk_toggle: "{target:'.my-class'}"} } %>
```

OR

```
<%= g.label :self_estimation, :class => 'km-180-label', "data-uk-toggle" => "{target:'.my-class'}" %>
```

OR

```
<%= g.label :self_estimation, :class => 'km-180-label', data: {uk_toggle: "{target:'.my-class'}"} %>
```

Answer (score -1):

This way you can add custom attribute.

```
<%= g.label :self_estimation, :class => 'km-180-label', :"data-uk-toggle" => "{target:'.my-class'}" %>
```

Comment: You need to remove ":" before "data-uk-toggle"

Comment: Ahh my bad just tested it will work, but don't see the point of adding an extra character(since it'll work without it) :)